# "Getting 'failed finding central directory' error when trying to run PyTorch model on DigitalOcean Droplet"

Tags: docker, pytorch, fastapi, digital-ocean, droplet

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to run a PyTorch model on a DigitalOcean Droplet. I can successfully run the model locally, but when I try to execute it on the Droplet, I get the following error: "RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory". How can I resolve this issue?

Below is the command I'm using and the error message I'm receiving:

[Command]: docker run -p 8000:8000 docker-name]
[Error message]:"RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory"

And here is my docker file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M3Pc.png)

I have verified the model file path, and I am confident it is correct. The model file is provided as a zip archive and works flawlessly locally.
But in Digital Ocean droplet, it throws error message above.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please include the code as text and not as image, see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also add some formating to improve your question, see: [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)